# Hereditarily indecomposable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

**Question.** Is it true that each uncountable group $G$ contains an uncountable subgroup $A$ and an infinite subgroup $B$ such that $A\cap B=\{1\}$? What will be the answer if we additionally require that $ab=ba$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Comment: If I recall correctly, for the abelian case the answer is positive. However it is easy to arrange a model without choice where there is an uncountable group which is indecomposable. In fact, you can even have it as a vector space over your favorite field if you want to.

Comment: Yes, the positive answer in the abelian case (in ZFC) is an exercise (any uncountable abelian group of cardinal $\alpha$ admits a subgroup that is a free $Z/pZ$-module of rank $\alpha$ for some $p$ either prime or zero). The nilpotent case seems to be not too hard to deduce.

Comment: An alternative approach to Mohammad's answer would be to have uncountable groups in which the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups is nonzero (which forces being torsion), or just such that the intersection any two nontrivial subgroups is nonzero (which forces being either torsion or torsion-free). However, I have not found anything in a quick Google search.

Comment: PS beware that the use of "indecomposable" and "hereditarily" are quite far from the standard uses.

Comment: @YCor I just wanted to call the problem somehow in an attractive way. But it relates anyway, if "decomposable" means "representable as the direct sum of two non-trivial factors".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not rue, by Shelah's construction of  a Jonsson group
of cardinality $\aleph_1$ (a group of size $\aleph_1$ for which every proper subgroup is countable). See [On a problem of Kurosh, Jónsson groups, and applications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08713466)

Comment: I cannot open the paper of Shelah :( Does his construction hold in ZFC or require some axiom (like diamond)?

Comment: @TarasBanakh it's a ZFC construction.